# Is the commentary by Ibn kathir about the abrogation of 2:256 real?

Tags: tafseer, islamic-scholar

> This is Ibn kathir tasfir.
>
> Allah says: "There is no compulsion in religion", meaning: do not force anyone to embrace Islam, because it is clear and its proofs and evidences are manifest. Whoever Allah guides and opens his heart to Islam has indeed embraced it with clear evidence. Whoever Allah misguides blinds his heart and has set a seal on his hearing and a covering on his eyes cannot embrace Islam by force...hence Allah revealed this verse. **But, this verse is abrogated by the verse of "fighting...Therefore, all people of the world should be called to Islam. If anyone of them refuses to do so, or refuses to pay the Jizya they should be fought till they are killed. This is the meaning of compulsion.** In the Sahih, the Prophet said: "Allah wonders at those people who will enter Paradise in chains", meaning prisoners brought in chains to the Islamic state, then they embrace Islam sincerely and become righteous, and are entered among the people of Paradise.

This is what ibn kathir says but I can't finds any of it in any website.[Quranx](https://quranx.com/tafsirs/2.256) have the commentary of Ibn kathir but it doesn't say any of this(abrogation of quran 2:256).

So where can I find it, or is this even real commentary by Ibn kathir

Comment: Of some relevance [Which verses are abrogated?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38244/which-qur'an-verses-are-abrogated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the parts of the tafsir was ommitted:

> ...وقد ذهب طائفة كثيرة من العلماء، أن هذه محمولة على أهل الكتاب، ومن
> دخل في دينهم قبل النسخ والتبديل إذا بذلوا الجزية، **وقا****ل آخرون بل هي
> م****نسوخة بآية القتال**
>
> Many of the scholars have said that these are based
> on the people of the Book and those who entered their religion prior
> to abrogation [of such religions by Islam] and alteration if they paid
> the poll tax [i.e. the Jizya]. **But others said that it is abrogated by**
> **the verse of fighting...**
>
> [Tafsir Ibn Kathir 2:256](https://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=7&tSoraNo=2&tAyahNo=256&tDisplay=yes&Page=1&Size=1&LanguageId=1)

This is from the Arabic text and can be found in the altafsir site. Imam Ibn Kathir said others said it was abrogated which indirectly shows he wasn't of this opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

The English translation of Tafsir Ibn Kathir which is available online is an *abridged* edition and does not carry they whole text, this is the reason that you can not find the text on most websites.

However the translation that you have quoted is also incomplete as it omits some words.

Tafsir Ibn Kathir includes the following text:

> وقد ذهب طائفة كثيرة من العلماء أن هذه محمولة على أهل الكتاب ومن دخل في
> دينهم قبل النسخ والتبديل إذا بذلوا الجزية . وقال آخرون : بل هي منسوخة
> بآية القتال وأنه يجب أن يدعى جميع الأمم إلى الدخول في الدين الحنيف دين
> الإسلام ، فإن أبى أحد منهم الدخول فيه ولم ينقد له أو يبذل الجزية ،
> قوتل حتى يقتل . وهذا معنى الإكراه قال الله تعالى : ( ستدعون إلى قوم
> أولي بأس شديد تقاتلونهم أو يسلمون ) [ الفتح : 16 ] وقال تعالى : ( يا
> أيها النبي جاهد الكفار والمنافقين واغلظ عليهم ) [ التحريم : 9 ] وقال
> تعالى : ( يا أيها الذين آمنوا قاتلوا الذين يلونكم من الكفار وليجدوا
> فيكم غلظة واعلموا أن الله مع المتقين ) [ التوبة : 123 ] وفي الصحيح : "
> عجب ربك من قوم يقادون إلى الجنة في السلاسل " يعني : الأسارى الذين يقدم
> بهم بلاد الإسلام في الوثائق والأغلال والقيود والأكبال ثم بعد ذلك
> يسلمون وتصلح أعمالهم وسرائرهم فيكونون من أهل الجنة
>
> Many scholars holds that this verse is specific to the
> Ahl al-Kitab ... when they accept payment of Jiyza.
>
> While others say: Rather this verse is abrogated. And it is obligatory
> to invite all people to accept Islam. And if they refuse to accept
> Islam and also refuse Jizya then they are to be fought until killed.
>
> And this is the meaning of compulsion - Allah has said: 'You will be
> called to [face] a people of great military might; you may fight them,
> or they will submit (i.e. embrace Islam)'  [[Al-Fath 16](https://quran.com/48/16?translations=20)]
>
> And Allah has said: 'O Prophet, strive against the disbelievers and
> the hypocrites and be harsh upon them.'  [[At-Tahrim 9](https://quran.com/66/9?translations=20)]
>
> And Allah has said: 'O you who have believed, fight those adjacent to
> you of the disbelievers and let them find in you harshness. And know
> that Allah is with the righteous.' [[At-Tawbah 123](https://quran.com/9/123?translations=20)]
>
> And in Sahih ([Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3010)): "Allah wonders at those people who will enter
> Paradise in chains."  - the meaning is those captives who enter the
> Islamic state as prisoners and after that they accept Islam and their
> deeds and hearts reform and hence they become part of the people of
> Paradise.
>
> (Ibn Kathir then also cites [this](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/9342)
> hadith but regards it as irrelevant)
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir Ibn al-Kathir](https://shamela.ws/book/23604/519) on verse 2:256</sup>